# Woocommerce Subscription Hooks/Filters not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written this function and placed it in my functions.php but for some reason it doesn't trigger, I have tried it as an action and a filter but no luck.

```
// ADD £40 ON SUCCESFUL SUBSCRIPTION PAYMENT (EXAMPLE 2)
function custom_add_funds_two($user_id) {

    // get current user's funds
    $funds = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', true );

    // add £40
    $funds = $funds + 40;

    // add funds to user
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', $funds );

}
add_filter('processed_subscription_payment','custom_add_funds_two');
```

Comment: Filters should return something.

Comment: There is no such filter as `processed_subscription_payment` in Woocommerce

Comment: WooCommerce Subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce Docs suggest that the hook you might be after could be:

```
woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete
```

or

```
woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete
```

[Source](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/)

So I would try:

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete','custom_add_funds_two');
```